# Counter example with series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$ to show that $ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor!} $ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am inspecting the convergence of different series and I ran across the following series:
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor!} $$.

I know that the following series shoud diverge, but unfortunately the D'Alembert's criterion gave me the answer zero. Furthermore the $\lim_{n} u_{n}$ seems to not go to zero . So I would like to give the counter example with the harmonic series:

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$$

to show that the first series diverge. Can someone show me how to do that counter example or have I totally missed the point and failed to understand the principles of series?

Comment: Why you think $u_{n}$ does not go to $0$? It seems to me factorial is much faster than exponent, starting from some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[\frac k 2] \geq (9!) 9^{[\frac k 2]-9}$ (since $9,10,11,..., [\frac k 2]$ are all $\geq 9$). Hence the series is dominated by a constant times the series $\sum \frac {2^{k}} {3^{3([\frac k 2]-9)}}$. Now observe that $3([\frac k 2]-9) \geq k$ for all $k$ sufficiently large. Comparing the given series with $\sum (\frac 2  3)^{k}$ we get convergence.

Comment: The first part is a bit confusing... At least we have not met these kind of terms in our high school or first year at university...

Comment: @Goodylan for $1 \leq k \leq n$ we have $(1)(2)... (n) \geq (1)(2)...(k) [(k)(k)...(k)]$ where there are $n-k$ factors in $[(k)(k)...(k)]$. For example $5! > (1)(2)[(2)(2)(2)]=(2!)2^{5-2}$.